# log4net: Logging two messages in one row in the database?

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to log the input and output of a particular method to the database.  I'd like to have this information in separate columns.  I've investigated the PatternLayout and it seems that it only caters for a single %message parameter, meaning that if you do:

```
log.Debug("This is a message");
```

then log4net sees "This is a message" as the message to be logged.  I want to do something like:

```
log.Debug(request, response);
```

Is this possible using log4net?  Keep in mind that my goal is to have "request" and "response" in **separate** columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PatternConverter way is a step in the right direction, though the use of the static Input and Output properties makes it all a bit shaky (thread-safety wise).

The trick here is to realize that the message parameter on logger.Debug(...) is object and that you can pass in whatever you like.

You could define a custom message type

```
public class InputOutput
{
    public string Input {get;set;}
    public string Output {get;set;}
}
```

and then let your converters read either property

```
public class InputPatternConverter : PatternConverter
{
    protected override void Convert(System.IO.TextWriter writer, object state)
    {
        var msg = ((LoggingEvent)state).MessageObject as InputOutput;
        if (msg != null)
            writer.Write(msg.Input);
    }
}

public class OutputPatternConverter : PatternConverter
{
    protected override void Convert(System.IO.TextWriter writer, object state)
    {
        var msg = ((LoggingEvent)state).MessageObject as InputOutput;
        if (msg != null)
            writer.Write(msg.Output);
    }
}
```

the logging then becomes much cleaner

```
logger.Debug(new InputOutput { Input = ..., Output = ...});
```

your config would be the same.

A tip though is to subclass the PatternLayout and add the converters in the constructor of that class. That way you can also trim down your config. This will *not* cause you to loose the %message token, your %input and %output tokens will come in addition to all the tokens that PatternLayout supports. So you could actually have a pattern like this:

```
"%date %message %newline%newline %input %newline%newline %output
```

Here's a quick implementation of a custom pattern layout:

```
public class InputOutputPatternLayout : PatternLayout
{
    public InputOutputPatternLayout()
    {
        AddConverter("input", typeof(InputPatternConverter));
        AddConverter("output", typeof(OutputPatternConverter));
    }
}
```

Comment: To make the usage less verbose, you could implement this as an extension method to the ILogger interface taking the two params. Then the usage would be something like: logger.Debug(input, output);

Comment: One limitation though is that you lose the "@message" parameter, unless you add another pattern converter (or maybe subclass PatterLayout?) and another property.  I haven't tested whether this works, but would it be advisable to override the ToString() method to return the @message (just to make it more generic) instead of having a separate pattern converter?

Comment: Oh and just a correction:  "state as InputOutput" should be something like "((LoggingEvent)state).MessageObject as InputOutput" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with one way to do this using custom PatternConverters

```
public class InputPatternConverter : PatternConverter
{
    private static string _input;

    public static string Input
    {
        get { return _input; }
        set { _input = value; }
    }

    protected override void Convert(System.IO.TextWriter writer, object state)
    {
        writer.Write(Input);
    }
}

public class OutputPatternConverter : PatternConverter
{
    private static string _output;

    public static string Output
    {
        get { return _output; }
        set { _output = value; }
    }

    protected override void Convert(System.IO.TextWriter writer, object state)
    {
        writer.Write(Output);
    }
}
```

Appender Specification:

```
<appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=servername;initial catalog=database;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO RequestLog ([input], [output]) VALUES (@input, @output)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@input" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <converter>
        <name value="input" />
        <type value="InputPatternConverter, ApplicationName" />
      </converter>
      <conversionPattern value="%input" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@output" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <converter>
        <name value="output" />
        <type value="OutputPatternConverter, ApplicationName" />
      </converter>
      <conversionPattern value="%output" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
</appender>
```

Call it using:

```
InputPatternConverter.Input = inputString;
OutputPatternConverter.Output = outputString;

XmlConfigurator.Configure();
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ApplicationClassName));
logger.Debug("");
```